# I need to write a Stored procedure to insert data in a column( unique constraint) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a Stored procedure to insert data in a column( unique constraint) in mysql  and first i have to check if column is null then i have to check for duplicate, if not then insert the random generated data.

BEGIN
DECLARE key1 VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE accid varchar(32);

```
WHILE ( select count(*) from account where customerkey is null)>0 DO

    SET key1 = (SELECT LEFT(MD5(UUID()), 7));

    WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM account  WHERE customerkey = key1) < 1 DO

        SET accid = (select id from account where customerkey is null limit 1);
        update account set customerkey = key1 where id = accid;

     END WHILE;

END WHILE;
```

END

Comment: Detail your question with sample data.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you___

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data/code/output, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have tried While loop but it is taking more time and not coming outside                                                                                       DECLARE key1 VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE accid varchar(32);
 WHILE ( select count(*) from account where customerkey is null)>=1 DO 
SET key1 = (SELECT LEFT(MD5(UUID()), 7));
select key1;
WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM account  WHERE customerkey = key1) < 1 DO
SET accid = (select id from account where customerkey is null limit 1);
 update account set customerkey = key1 where id = accid;       
   END WHILE;
   
 END WHILE;
  
END

Comment: Then I suggest editing your question. This is a simple problem in SQL, but a clearer question will help.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need a loop or separate variables in the procedure. Based on what you've posted, you should be able to get away with a single update statement:

```
update account set customerkey = LEFT(MD5(UUID()), 7) where customerkey is null;
```

Try that and let me know if it does the trick.

As an aside reassurance, yes, UUID() returns unique for each row.

Comment: It is working on my local as i have only 9000 records but on my development DB we have 250000 column So LEFT(MD5(UUID()), 7) creating duplicate records. That's why i am doing " WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM account  WHERE customerkey = key1) < 1" . BUT it is not coming out the loop.

Comment: First off, hash collisions are beyond the scope of the question. Using MD5 will generate hash collisions, let alone taking just a simple substring of it. I recommend finding a new function or method of generating new unique data - or expanding the column size to store a simple UUID() as a string. Using a substring of MD5 and expecting it to be unique is the start of that next problem. I recommend asking a new question about how to get 10 characters worth of unique data, and plug that into the update statement. Also, get rid of the loop.